# Frequency Table that Excludes Digits

Tags: statistics

What do you do when a frequency table has results that skips digits, e.g the results are 1,1,3,3,4,4,5,5. Notice the lack of the digit 2. Would the table include 2 and have a frequency of 0 or just not include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way would be correct. But if the context is that integer values from 1 through 5 are possible values, then I think it would be best to include 2 with a frequency of 0.

For example, if these are numbers of people in eight households, it might be useful to emphasize that no households with exactly 2 people were encountered. The purpose of tables, bar charts, etc. is to provide information in a way that is easy to grasp quickly. So when there are options it is best to take the one that will be most informative for your audience.